# flex 4 mobile problem with ViewNavigatorApplication states and firstView

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm having a crack at making my first Flex mobile application (although I'm not new to Flex), and I've tripped at the first hurdle.

I cannot get **ViewNavigatorApplication** to display a view when trying to use **firstView** with states e.g. **firstView.phone**, **firstView.tablet**.

I'm just left with a blank action bar and content area.

If I try setting setting **firstView** with no state (e.g. **firstView="view.HomeView"**) the view loads fine.

Here's the code:

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView.phone="views.HomeView"
    firstView.tablet="views.TabletHomeView"
    applicationDPI="160" 
    creationComplete="initApplication()">
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portraitPhone" stateGroups="portrait, phone"/>
        <s:State name="landscapePhone" stateGroups="landscape, phone"/>
        <s:State name="portraitTablet" stateGroups="portrait, tablet"/>
        <s:State name="landscapeTablet" stateGroups="landscape, tablet"/>
    </s:states>
    <fx:Style source="assets/css/application.css"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            private var isPortrait:Boolean;
            private var isTablet:Boolean;

            private function initApplication():void
            {               
                addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, resizeHandler);
            }

            private function resizeHandler(event:*):void
            {
                isPortrait = (stage.height > stage.width);
                isTablet = (stage.height > 950 || stage.width > 950);

                currentState = (isPortrait ? "portrait" : "landscape") + (isTablet ? "Tablet" : "Phone");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

I've googled this to death, read though the [**ViewNavigatorApplication** specification](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/View+and+ViewNavigator) and not found anyone else with this problem or any evidence that I'm simply doing it wrong (although i still suspect that is the case).

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I'm still learning myself, but if I understand, you don't want to create states like this in the ViewNavigatorApplication.  It's just a dummy container, in essence.  Create States like this in a View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went with @www.Flextras.com comment [not put in as an answer]:

> I'm still learning myself, but if I understand, you don't want to
>   create states like this in the ViewNavigatorApplication. It's just a
>   dummy container, in essence. Create States like this in a View.

I emptied the ViewNavigatorApplication of all the States & code like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    applicationDPI="160"
    splashScreenImage="com.mis.editor.mobile.sire.components.DynamicSplash"
    runtimeDPIProvider="com.mis.editor.mobile.helpers.RuntimeDPIHelper"
    firstView="SplashView">
    <fx:Style source="com/mis/editor/mobile/sire/assets/css/application.css"/>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

I put code in the first view to detect if the device is a phone / tablet and redirect to the appropriate View:

```
protected function push_login():void
{           
    var fadeTrans:CrossFadeViewTransition = new CrossFadeViewTransition();

    if(ScreenDetails.Format == 'phone')
    {
        navigator.pushView(PhoneLoginView, appDataMediator, null, fadeTrans);
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.pushView(LoginView, appDataMediator, null, fadeTrans);
    }           
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write states inside views not in viewNavigatorApplication(Defines the main application file. The ViewNavigatorApplication container does not take any children.)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to have states in your view navigator if the views themselves are states?  I fairly sure it's not meant to be used that way and that it isn't possible to 'load' a new view through first view.  Just set the firstView and after it loads and switch the views accordingly.

If you want to do something that 'resizes', I would add the resizing code to each view *or* have a separate application for each form factor to give a better experience while reusing your code (this is my preferred method).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting the firstView property from actionscrtip after calculating the size of the screen. Just make sure you do that in preinitialize event. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: If you're not sure of your answer's correctness, post it as a comment, not an answer.